# AttributeError: module 'fasttext.util' has no attribute 'download_model'

Tags: python, fasttext

When I try to run

```
import fasttext.util
fasttext.util.download_model('en', if_exists='ignore')
```

I get the following error

```
AttributeError: module 'fasttext.util' has no attribute 'download_model'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The pip installation of fasttext is missing some modules, the solution is

```
pip uninstall fasttext
```

and

```
git clone https://github.com/facebookresearch/fastText.git
cd fastText
sudo pip install .
```